# Fullcalendar v4 refetch only one single event

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I'm trying to figure out the proper way to refetch one single event (when I add an event and when I update an event)

I'm currently using `calendar.refetchEvents();` which will refetch all the events after adding/updating an event but it would be better if I could only refetch that single event.

I use events as a function like so

```
eventSources: [

    {
        events:function(fetchinfo, successCallback, failureCallback) {

            $.ajax({
                type:'GET',
                url: '/rdv/data',
                data:{
                    start:moment(fetchinfo.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'),
                    end:moment(fetchinfo.end).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'),
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    let arrayEvents = [];
                    $.each(data, function (key) {
                        arrayEvents.push( {
                        title: "title",
                        start: data[key].date_debut_rdv,
                        end: data[key].date_fin_rdv,
                        extendedProps: {
                            id: data[key].id,
                            nom_client: data[key].animal.client.nom_client,
                            prenom_client: data[key].animal.client.prenom_client,
                            id_client: data[key].animal.client.id,
                            nom_animal: data[key].animal.nom_animal,
                        },
                    });
                });

                successCallback(arrayEvents);

                },
                error: function(data){
                    //
                }
            })
        }
    }
]
```

Add an event inside a dateClick

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/rdvs/ajoutRdv",
    data: {
        _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}",
        client_id: client_id,
        animal_id: animal_id,
        date_debut_rdv: date_debut_rdv,
        statut_rdv_id: statut_rdv_id,
        prestations: prestations,
        tvas: tvas,
        supplements: supplements,
        },
        success: function () {
            calendar.refetchEvents();
            $('#modalEditRdv').modal('hide');
        },
        error: function(data) {
            //
        });
    }
})
```

Update an event inside an eventClick

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/rdvs/click/"+id,
    data: {
        _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}",
        rdv_id: event.event.extendedProps.id,
        client_id: client_id,
        animal_id: animal_id,
        date_debut_rdv: date_debut_rdv,
        statut_rdv_id: statut_rdv_id,
        prestations: prestations,
        tvas: tvas,
        supplements: supplements,
    },
    success: function (data) {
        calendar.refetchEvents();

        //I could do something like this without making a request to the server
        //but is there another way ?
        //event.event.setExtendedProp("nom_animal", data[0].nom_animal);
        //event.event.setStart(data[1]);
        //event.event.setEnd(data[2]);

        $('#modalEditRdv').modal('hide');
    },
    error: function(data) {
        //
    }
})
```

I see there is `EventSource::refetch` but it would refetch all the events as well if I'm correct ?

A little help would be very appreciated,

Thank you !

Comment: The way you've done it is the standard way to do it and is completely fine. Are you experiencing a specific performance issue relating to refetching the events? Remember that (assuming you've written your server-side code correctly) it won't download **all** your events, only the ones which fall between the start and end dates of the current calendar display.

Comment: Yeah, it only fetches the wanted events to display on the current view. I was just wondering if I could diminish the requests I'd make to the server. As for updating, I would just update the informations related to the event already on the calendar, render it with it's new properties but without having the need to make a request and fetching again.

Comment: well if your POST method to create the event will return the new ID of the event in the response, then you can then use Javascript to create a new event object and give it [directly to fullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-addEvent). The only problem is if something else occurs later which refetches the events, you can end up with the same event twice on the calendar if you're not careful. For updating you can also update an event using the [setProp](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Event-setProp) and related methods - but I think you know this already from your commented-out code

Comment: Alright, I think I will keep it as it is now. I'll keep in mind that and I'll apply the changes if I need them. Thank you for all the answers you provide about this plugin !